# timing issues in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

i'm having trouble understanding how to correctly handle assignments in node callbacks. I'm reading a config file and setting it's values in an express app using props to parse the .yaml. When i try and use what i've apparently set i can't app.get these values. (cfg_decoder is required from the props module). The console.log() works properly in the callback but how to I handle app.get outside of the callback or know when the values have been set?

```
app = express()

fs.readFile('./config.yaml', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  cfg = cfg_decoder(data);
  app.set('title', cfg['title'])
  app.set('port', cfg['port'])

  console.log(app.get('title'))

});
```

On a side note, is this a good way of setting configuration options?

Comment: This is a good way to manage the configuration options.
The problem is that you can't get the values set in the callback outside of it?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the app.get() method within any scope as long as the express object has been instantiated.

You could have your fs.readFile() function return your settings values and then have app.set() be done outside of the scope of the read function.

```
function read(file){
    var content;
    fs.readFileSync(file, function (err, data) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        content = cfg_decoder(data);
    });
    return content;
}

var config = read('./config.yaml');
app.set('title', cfg['title'])
app.set('port', cfg['port'])
```

For my applications I use a config.js file or you could use a config.json file (which would be easier). In my .js file I just have an object array declaration and have it export out that object.

**Config.js**:

```
var config = {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '8000',
    title: 'Title',
    /* etc */
};
module.exports = config;
```

**App.js**:

```
var config = require('./config'),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.set('title', config.title);
app.listen(config.port, config.host);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: wow this is a much better way of doing things, i was using yaml because i felt it was the cleanest but this method is so much easier. This is also much cleaner code, thanks.

Comment: Your example won't work unless you use the synchronous version of `fs.readFile`; without at least one trip around the event loop (which your code doesn't allow) the return value of `read()` is going to be `undefined`. In this particular case, it's actually reasonable to use `fs.readFileSync` since you can't really do anything else until the config file's been read, but the pattern isn't generalizable.

Comment: Thanks for catching that I did not mean to write down the synchronous version, updated.